# failing to import code from a different file playwright?

Tags: python, playwright

current goal is to import code from 1 file and run it in another but i getting this error

```
Job "runF5 (trigger: interval[1 day, 0:00:00], next run at: 2023-01-31 00:24:00 PKT)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pyton\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "e:\completed zameen project\combined.py", line 11, in runF5
    m5.runF5(playwright)
  File "e:\completed zameen project\m5.py", line 131, in runF5
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=600)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'playwright' has no attribute 'chromium'
```

code in file 1
i intend to import the function runF5 from file 1 to file 2

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
#import playwright
import random
import time
import sys
import pyautogui


def runF5(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=600)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.google.com/', timeout=0)
    #time.sleep(1)
```

code in file 2 which is importing the code from file 1

```
import playwright
import schedule
import datetime
import time
import m5
import schedule
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def runF5():
    # code to run at 03:30
    m5.runF5(playwright)

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(runF5, 'interval', days=1, start_date='2022-01-01 03:31:00', timezone='Asia/Karachi')
scheduler.start()

# Keep the program running
while True:
    pass
```

i was expected at the given time the code will run and open google but i keeping getting the error
i always change the time so the codes runs 2mins from now- for testing

Comment: code runs fine if ran from inside file 1